# jquery toggle tab - need to collapse outer container that has overflow:hidden set

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'd be eternally grateful if someone could assist me (a newb at jquery) with this hopefully easy to solve issue.

Please see this test:

http://the3rdobject.com/test3/index.html

Everything works well from the off, except for one thing - I'm trying to collapse the outer red box when the close tab is clicked, the panel closes perfectly but unfortunately the outer container remains open. The reason I'm trying to get this to work is this tab appears over the top of a carousel slider and while the panel remains open it prevents swipe functionality over part of the underlying image.

My jquery is just adding and removing a class to control the height. It works successfully adding the class but won't remove it. I'm sure this is simple, but my jquery is flaky at best.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".collectionbutton").click(function(){
            if($(".collectionbutton a").hasClass('openpanel')){
                $(".text").animate({top:'-' + $(".text-content-container").css('height') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".collectionbutton a").toggle();
                $(".text-wrap").addClass('heightchange');
            } else {
                $(".text").animate({top:$(".text-content-container").css('') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".collectionbutton a").addClass('openpanel');
            }   
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I've tried adding:

```
$(".text-wrap").removeClass('heightchange');
```

within all positions of the else statement but it just will not remove the class. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle

Comment: I've never used it before... do i need to paste everything into each box? There's a lot of stuff connected up as I've stripped this test out of the site I'm building so there's a lot of stuff linking that prob may not be in use - I guess it's a bit awkward to troubleshoot otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this and see if it works...

```
$(function(){
        $(".collectionbutton a").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('openpanel')){
                $(".text").animate({top:'-' + $(".text-content-    container").css('height') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".collectionbutton a").toggle();
                $(".text-wrap").removeClass('heightchange',{duration:500});

            } else {
                $(".text").animate({top:$(".text-content-container").css('') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".text-wrap").addClass('heightchange',{duration:500});
                $(".collectionbutton a").toggle();

            }   
        });
    });
```

//  Try this new code....should work fine now..

```
$(function(){
        $(".collectionbutton a").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('openpanel')){
                $(".text").animate({top:'-' + $(".text-content-container").css('height') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".collectionbutton a").toggle();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".text-wrap").removeClass('heightchange');
                }, 500);

            } else {
                $(".text").animate({top:$(".text-content-container").css('') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".text-wrap").addClass('heightchange');
                $(".collectionbutton a").toggle();

            }   
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have already tried removing the class within the else statement and this doesn't work at all - this is the problem. The class successfully adds within the if statement as per the code I posted above. i can try what you've posted but i believe this will still cauuse issues.

Comment: Hi there - Your solution has worked in some way as it opens perfectly and now it does actually collapse the container - however, it doesn't complete the second animation of closing the panel before collapsing the outer container - feels like progress of some sort though!!! Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there, scrap that... it does animate (it wasn't due to the space in the class name (see your code above), but now that it's amended, it's animating both ways but the height collapses and crops the second animation before completion. is there a way of executing the height collapse on completion of the animation?

Comment: see my edits, does it not collapse the height on completion of animation?

Comment: Interesting, so just adding the duration delays it... clever!

Comment: u r welcome!  please mark it as answer if it has helped you! thanks!